# Detect multiple switches in series individually

Tags: switches

I have a device, which has a safety relay, where the relay coil is connected to +12V over 2 reed switches.
Now I want to detect, which of the reed switches is not closed, with a microcontroller, but I struggle a bit with that.

I have seen something like this before, but I cannot remember how it can be done with resistors and transistors only. I tried the following, which does not work for SW2 closed. Anyone an idea, how this can be done?

[image: Safety Path]

Comment: Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: To do what you want you need to bridge each switch with a resistor to form a voltage divider with enough current to raise the voltage to a detectable level at RLY1 but not enough to hold it on when one or both of the switches opens. I'm concerned about your mention of reed switches and safety though. Can you [edit] to include some details?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/624007/how-to-detect-welded-contacts-of-a-redundant-relay-for-reliable-high-current-e/624143?noredirect=1#comment1649188_624143) if you replace the LEDs by solid state relays. You may have to adapt the resistor values to meet the selected SSR's specs.