# Switch in series, check individually if one is open or closed

Tags: microcontroller, relay

I have a safety path for a relay, that disables the power when one of two switches is triggered. To detect, which switch is triggered, I tried to implement something like the following, but it is still not working correctly, since it will only detect, when S2 is closed or open. It only works, when the supply for the logic is 12V instead of 3.3V

[image]

I need to convert the signal to 3.3V for the uC. Do you have any improvments on the scheme? I don't want to go with optocouplers, since they need around 1mA of current, which will energize the relay coil too much.

Comment: As in your previous question,  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/501602/detect-multiple-reed-switches-in-series-individually, I am concerned that you are using reed relays in a safety circuit. Bypassing the contacts with the monitoring circuit risks a non fail-safe failure mode. What is the application?

Comment: If the switches are mechanical switches, why not use a double pole switch, one for controlling the relay and one for monitoring the status of the switch ?

Comment: In this circuit, if L1 or  R12 becomes open circuit for some reason, is the circuit still expected to show the status of the switches ?

Comment: What type of micro-controller are you using? Does it have GPIO pins that you can read the status of the switches with and control the relay directly or are you monitoring the switches independently of the switching of the relay? Could you drive your switches from a 3V3 supply and use TTL/CMOS logic instead of the discrete components?

Comment: I'm not using a reed relay, its an automotive relay: https://www.mouser.ch/ProductDetail/TE-Connectivity-AMP/V23076A3001C132?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsqIr59i2oRckZsBLqSf8bop2F82LoGRSg%3D

The application is a running motor, where the power supply  should be deenergized in case of a switch is triggering

I'm using an STM32 uC, so I have GPIO to read the status of the switch.

I want to monitor the switches independet of the relay switching, that's why there will be parallel resitor to the MOSFET, that switches the relay

Answer (score 0):

Here's a relay-based solution.

[image]