# How to detect welded contacts of a redundant relay? (for reliable high-current e-Stop)

Tags: voltage, current, switches, relay

I want to switch ON/OFF a load with an e-Stop backup - the issue is that the load is 20ADC.

So the load is switched by a suitable relay (SPST-NO), which is itself controlled by the ON/OFF switch in series with the e-Stop.

The problem is that if the relay fails shorted (i.e. welded contacts), the e-Stop does not work. My solution to this is to have two relay contacts in series, and try to detect when one of them welds (it is likely both will not weld at the exact same time).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuzBhx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The challenge stems from the requirements:

- The supply voltage is 36V
- The load can vary between 1.8R and 10k. It is safe to assume 10k is after the load is switched on, 1.8R later on. This translates to a maximum 20A drawn.
- I would not like to dissipate more than about a Watt in this system
- No voltage drop is to be added in the "ON" state.
- The maximum voltage that the load can see when the system is switched off is 0.6V, even when one of the switches is welded shut. This is somewhat what I assume is a safe "OFF" voltage for the load (we never know with systems which don't have undervoltage protections).
- The detection must be immediately noticed when switching the load OFF by the operator

I have thought for hours now, and the closest I've gotten was to have a 2mA LED and 15k series resistor both in parallel of each switch - but I had to load the bus with a power resistor which dissipated 4W to meet the "max OFF voltage" requirement.

The obvious solution would be to use relays with auxiliary contacts (assuming both contacts are in contact when one is welded), but I'd like to avoid adding requirements on the choice of the relays. And this got my curiosity...

The goal is to find the SIMPLEST solution, e.g. with a few resistors, LEDs, fuses etc.

Comment: the relay contact could operate a microswitch when the contact opens ... better still, operate the contacts with a big red button, not with a relay

Comment: There's safety relays for this. The contact arm that is being actuated has a intentional weak spot so that it breaks when it has to open but the contacts stick.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEQqdW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

One 14-pin jellybean chip, a few resistors or networks and one LED.

OA1 and OA2 form a window comparator that, ignoring OA3, turns on LED D1 if (SW1 is closed) or (SW2 is closed).

OA3 turns the LED off if both are closed at the same time, so the LED is only on if one of SW1 or SW2 is closed.

Comment: Except your load will be energized via R6 and R7.  *This has been driving me nuts.*

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine The voltage even with a 10K load will be less than the 600mV that OP specifies.

Comment: I wanted to avoid using active components but in this category, it's a very interesting solution with a low parts count still, and I'm happy to have read it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this works as-is? When SW1 is closed for example, the left opamps have a different saturated output and therefore try to fight for the LED's cathode.

Comment: @MisterMystère LM339 is a quad comparator with open-collector outputs. They can only pull low.

Comment: My bad, mixed it up with another part number. Nice solution btw, +1

Answer (score 2):

(I misunderstood the question to start with, but I think the answer to that could still be useful, so I'll leave it up, below the break.)

### Answer to the correct question:

**There are contactors with auxiliary contacts that are designed for just that purpose.  Their entire purpose is to indicate the position of the main contacts, and so they *are* mechanically coupled to them.  They're often used as "proof switches" for on/off motors and similar devices: if the proof doesn't follow the command within a short time, throw a fault for that device.**

**You can get them from any industrial electrical supply place, and you could use them just as well to indicate the status of a safety shut-off.**

---

### Answer to the misunderstood question:

My first thought was that a lot of newer industrial safety circuits that I've seen do not power the load as you show.  They're something like this instead:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMxhl1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Each of the now-parallel contacts in the safety circuit is still mechanically independent, just like the series version, so that if one welds the other still works.  And the Safety Relay does not send constant power to each side, but a unique test signal so it can also detect crossed wires, jumpers to constant power, jumpers to a different Safety Relay, etc.  All of that is treated as a fault, just as if a switch had opened.  It also ignores a reset signal unless it has just seen both sides cycle *correctly* at the same time.

Of course, you can buy one from any industrial electrical supply place, or you could make one from those requirements.  I'll leave the details of construction and risk-assessment up to the student.  (don't forget the failure modes of the safety system itself!)

The only real improvement is to have a separate safety circuit for each individual switch, so you can tell exactly which one it was (or still is).  And some systems do in fact do that.

There are also (expensive!) redundant PLC's that have the safety I/O and certified/user-inaccessible logic built-in and connected to a software API instead of screw terminals.  Limited instruction set for the safety stuff: just connect the appropriate inputs, outputs, and custom reset logic to the pre-fab black-box logic-blocks.  Then add a password and sign/hash the code and save the key so you can deny legal liability if it's found to have changed since then.  (It requires that password to unsign, it won't allow changes without unsigning, and it uses the precise system time as a salt.  So even an *opportunity* to have changed it is enough to transfer liability, even if that opportunity wasn't taken.)  And now you have an officially-certified safety system that runs in software on a PLC.

### Then I realized that no matter what you do, you still have the same fault-detection problem with X1 and X2 as with anything else.

**That's really what the question is about, and so I put my answer to that up top.**

I'll still keep the "modern" safety circuit here, as it may still be useful to someone.  (it's really not that modern anymore)

Comment: You were right to keep your answer here, it was interesting to read :)

Answer (score 1):

Have an "off light". **Remember, the "stuck contact" condition simply cannot be detected while the machine is intended to be on**.

Use DPDT relays.

On one pole, use the NO contacts for your current use.

On the other pole, use the NC contacts.  Wire both relay's NC contacts in series.  That will have continuity when both relays are fully off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXWRGP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm afraid you can't be any more clever than that, because the armature is likely to tram somewhat if one contact welds down. That means the other contact may lift off the pad, causing it to be connected to nothing at all.

Or, much more simply, detect only one stuck relay.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx2aMn.png)</sup>

Comment: I really wanted to avoid changing the relay, but I must say this is really appealing. DPDT relays are not as widespread as SPDTs but maybe I can find one that meets the switching voltage. Thanks! I'll wait for other answers but I'll do that if I can find a DPDT that works.

Comment: It's just AWFUL to find a DPDT relay that works at 36VDC 20A... Hours again on that. I really liked this solution but looks like it doesn't work for me :( Still glad to have read this one!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. Although DPDTs are challenging to find in the VDC and current ratings you require, automotive SPDTs are readily available. With those, you can do the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRKFUy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- When SW1 and SW2 are open (normal OFF), D1 lights up at 32% brightness and D2 at 64% brightness, with a current of 3.2mA
- When SW1 and SW2 are closed (normal ON), none of the LEDs light up
- When SW1 is open but SW2 is stuck closed, D1 lights up at 52% brightness with a current of 5.2mA if the load is at its lightest (10k), full brightness when it's at its highest (1.8R)
- When SW1 is stuck closed and SW2 is open, D2 lights up at full brightness with a current of 5mA

You can play around with the resistor values to tune the LED brightnesses the closest to your liking, but 25% brightness is plenty to tell if a LED is ON or not.

0.275W is wasted in R3 when the equipment is ON, which is less than your requirement.

The advantage that I see in this solution is that the load is fully isolated in normal OFF circumstances and even in case of a fault.

Just add the following labels: D1 = "SW1 OK" and D2 = "SW2 OK", and a common label "Assert when OFF:" above.

When the equipment is switched off, look at the LEDs and if either is not lit, replace the corresponding relay.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks a lot!

Comment: For SW1 at least, you might even use an SPST contact, and rely entirely on the light being shorted to turn it off.  That would eliminate some uncertainty in how the switch works mechanically, and what the effect is if it's different from your assumption.  (by design or by failure)