# Is there a way to predict the VDC rating of a relay in function of its VAC rating?

Tags: voltage, current, switches, relay, maximum-ratings

I need a 36VDC 20A DPDT (c.f. [answer to some other question I had](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/624007/how-to-detect-welded-contacts-of-a-redundant-relay-for-reliable-high-current-e/624026#624026)) - resistive load mostly -, but can't find any. I have found [candidate relays](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/418/8/ENG_DS_1308242_T92_0421-713884.pdf) though, that have been tested at 28VDC 20A, 470VAC 20A, 400VAC 30A, and 600VAC 10A. I have the gut feeling 36VDC 20A is covered by these, but I'd like to have some theory to support this extrapolation.

For example, 250VAC 10A / 30VDC 10A are common. Does that mean that a 470VAC 20A is equally able to handle 56VDC 20A?

Comment: Do you want to risk it though? https://youtu.be/Zez2r1RPpWY?t=45

Comment: Not so sure about that to be honest because I think it's conceivable that the 600VAC 10A switch's contact spacing could be designed so the 600VAC couldn't jump across that distance as the top priority which isn't the same as withstanding a 20A DC arcing current that could conceivably contain more energy behind it especially if there was an inductance. They might be completely different design approaches and methods to the contacts.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can say for certain about the DC rating of a relay is that it will be less, much, much less, than its AC rating.

There are various features the relay designers can use to increase the ratings of their relays. A higher contact opening speed will improve DC breaking ratings. A higher temperature contact plating will improve all ratings. A higher contact pressure will improve current carrying ratings. A heavier contact blade may improve its thermal conductivity and thermal mass, but will reduce its opening speed. You might try to infer which of these the relay has, and which DC or AC or voltage they improve from the shape of the specifications. Good luck.

Don't forget that the numbers you see on a relay data sheet are **ratings**, measured under certain conditions. What residual inductance did the resistive test load have? What was the actual inductance of the inductive load? They are unlikely to match your use case exactly.

> I have the gut feeling 36VDC 20A is covered by these, but I'd like to have some theory to support this extrapolation.

No. If you look carefully, you'll see the highest DC voltage quoted is 28 V, at the same 20 A current. You can't even use the 'same VA' psuedo-argument.

It's unlikely the relay would fail first click at 36 V. It's certain you won't get the same lifetime from it than you would at 28 V. It's almost completely irrelevant what the AC ratings are.